# How to set a password in generated PDF from fpdm(Fpdf) library class?

Tags: php, codeigniter, pdf, fpdf

I want to know how to set a password in a PDF generated from fpdm(fpdf) library , I tried integrating the password protection of fpdf in fpdm library but it doesn't work.

Library used: http://www.fpdf.org/en/script/script93.php
Framework: Codeigniter
Database: SQL Server
My Code:

```
$fields = array(
    'name'    => 'My name',
);

$pdf = new FPDM('MyTemplate.pdf');
$pdf->Load($fields, false);
$pdf->Merge();
$pdf->Output();
```

Comment: Follow this tutorial http://www.fpdf.org/en/script/script37.php

Comment: Yes, that's is the one i tried and it doesn't work since it's calling fpdf. I tried to copy that class and remove the fpdf require to fpdm and it doesn't work.